# How can I make this Navigation menu responsive (I mean the social icons)?

Tags: css, wordpress, css-selectors

Here's the website: www.practicalized.com

[Here is how the mobile version looks right now.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DX3M.png)

[Here is how I want it to look like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVfeJ.png)

Tha nav menu is generated by the Wordpress theme, but the social icons were created by a friend of mine.

Here's the markup:

```
<div class="social-media-icons" style=" float: right; margin-top: -30px;">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Practicalized-264476844086337/" target="_blank" style="margin-right:4px;">
            <img src="http://localhost/practicalized/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/facebook-1.png" width="30" height="30">
        </a>
        <a href="https://twitter.com/Practicalizedx/" target="_blank" style="margin-right:4px;">
            <img src="http://localhost/practicalized/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/twitter-icon-1.png" width="30" height="30">
        </a>
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/practicalized/" target="_blank">
            <img src="http://localhost/practicalized/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/instagram-icon-1.png" width="30" height="30">
        </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please add the markup here

Comment: Karthick, I added the markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the inline styles from .social-media-icons

and add this in your css. I am assuming the expectation of the icons being in center is just for Mobile and not Desktop

```
 .social-media-icons {
   float:right; 
    margin-top: -30px; 
 }

 @media only screen and (max-width: 990px) {
    .social-media-icons {
      text-align: center;
      float: none;
      margin-top: auto;
    }
 }
```

Comment: It worked, but the icons appear in the center on the desktop. You see I want the icons to be on the right when on desktop but in the middle on mobile devices.

Comment: @EagleTsar Updated it. Please add this

Comment: @EagleTsar: No problem. If it solves the purpose. Kindly accept this as the answer

Comment: I have another question if you don't mind. Those social icons don't show up as icons on mobile and tablet, there is only an image icon. I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: @EagleTsar All the images have a hardcoded path with localhost "http://localhost/practicalized/ ". Try to give a relative path. or change every icon path to 
 "http://www.practicalized.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/instagram-icon-1.png" this format with their respective file names

Comment: Thank you, Karthick. You helped me a lot.